# Widget won't hide

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I guess this silly question but why doesn't my widget hide after is shown?

```
void Dialog::on_tabWidget_selected(const QString &arg1){
    QWidget *w = new QWidget();
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex() == 3){
             w -> move(1093,278);
             w -> setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
             w -> setFixedSize(206,206);
             w -> show();
     }else{
        w ->hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to hide it why you kept w->hide() in else block?

Answer (score 3):

The second time, it creats a new QWidget, so the hide does not affect the old widget if that's what you want to do.
Maybe you should explain a little bit more what is the result expected ?

EDIT:
if you want to display a popup when this tab is open, just use the widget's showEvent and hideEvent.
Or you can remove the "widget *w = new widget();", add "QWidget *w;" to the *.h, and add "w = new QWidget();" to the constructor, and it should work.

Comment: i want my widget by visible only on one tab

Comment: Okey I think you really don't understand how QTabWidget works.
I'll edit my post with an example

Comment: my QWidget is another window

Comment: Yes I saw that too late, so you can just use the widget's showEvent and hideEvent to show/hide the popup

Comment: But if you want to use the code you posted here, you can remove the "widget *w = new widget();", add "QWidget *w;" to the *.h, and add "w = new QWidget();" to the constructor, and it should work.